# $\mathbb{R^2} $and $ \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ difference?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I have read that you can '*identify*' $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$. My question is what does *identify* actually mean in linear algebra? And second question: isn't it the same? As an element $x\in \mathbb{R}^2 $ is defined as $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R^2} $ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Thanks

Comment: If you define $\mathbb R\times\mathbb R$ as $(a,b)\mid a,b\in\mathbb R$, which is a pretty standard way of constructing the cartesian product, these sets are identical. So there is no need to identify them as each other, since they are literally the same set.

Comment: Is there another way of understanding/interpreting it ? I dont know any other way, and what does identify mean ?

Comment: There are a lot of ways. But they express the same information, so it doesn't really matter. That's why we often prefer the categorical notion of product, since it is agnostic to the method of encoding ordered pairs. Identify means create a map between sets that identifies which element of the first set is supposed the represent it in the second set.

Comment: Could you give a link for that?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory) (P.S. The wiki page is quite terse, and might be a bit hard to understand. I'd pick up an intro to category theory book for a more gentle intro).

Comment: Do note that in linear algebra, the [slightly] less trivial identification usually mentioned is $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R} \leftrightarrow \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, and it's possible either of these could be intended with the $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Brian or Don could one of you please give an answer in the answer section which is detailed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a small notational difference here. Given two sets $A$ and $B$ the notation $A^B$ is the collection of all function from $B$ to $A$. When we write $A^n$ this refers to the set of all functions from a some set of cardinality $n$ to $A$. Say for $\mathbb{R}^3$ we might choose the set with three letters $\{x,y,z\}$ to be the set of three elements. An example of one of the functions in $\mathbb{R}^3$ would be $f(x)=1,f(y)=2,f(z)=3$.

Now instead of working over the set of functions we could instead write each function in coordinate form by creating the ordered tuple $(f(x),f(y),f(z))$ which for the example would correspond to the tuple $(1,2,3)$. This can be understood as the $x$ coordinate being $1$, the $y$ coordinate being $2$ and the $z$ coordinate being $3$. This gives us a bijection between the set of all functions from $\{x,y,z\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and the ordered triples of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. It's this bijection that allows us to identify $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: from {,,} to ℝ and the ordered triples of ℝ×ℝ×ℝ. i dont understand this, could you explain that in detail

Comment: @Maths Think of the letters as the name of the coordinate. The $x$ coordinate is the first one, the $y$ the second, and $z$ the third. The functions encodes which value corresponds to each coordinate, and there is one such function for each point in $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ since knowing the value of $f$ at each value in $\{x,y,z\}$ completely defines the function.